# Rails localize path without locale param for certain url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I am fairly new to Rails and in the process of building localization for my rails project. I have followed Rails i18n guide and is able to use localized path to different language version of the site.

My `routes.rb` looks like the following:

```
scope "/:locale" do
  # blah
end

namespace :admin do
  # admin blah
end
```

However because I have used `default_url_options` in application controller as suggested in Rails guide, the path generated by URL helper will also contain locale params. When I create link to my admin root `localhost:3000/admin?locale=en`, I will get an error saying `"admin" is not a valid locale`

Is there a way to make exception for the generated url to not including the locale parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a workaround for this. All I needed to do is to place the admin namespace routing before the scoped routes, such as

```
namespace :admin do
  # admin blah
end

scope "/:locale" do
  # blah
end
```

After I set it up like above, the error went away.